# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in swift completion block

Tags: ios, swift

i have getting error when i am executing this code.I use shopify framework for fetching collection but it crash the app. Please help me

```
self.client = BUYClient(shopDomain: self.shopDomain, apiKey: self.apiKey, appId: self.appID)
        self.client.getCollectionsPage(1, completion: {( collections:[BUYCollection]?, page: UInt, reachedEnd: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (collections != nil) && error == nil {
                print("fetching collections: \(collections)")
                self.data=collections! as NSArray
                self.fetchProducts()

            }
            else {
                print("Error fetching collections: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } as! BUYDataCollectionsListBlock //here an error occur 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by changing NSError to ERROR

```
 self.client.getCollectionsPage(1, completion: {( collections:[BUYCollection]?, page: UInt, reachedEnd: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in

    if (collections != nil) && error == nil {
        print("fetching collections: \(collections)")
        self.data=collections! as NSArray
        self.fetchProducts()
    }
    else {
        print("Error fetching collections: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```